# Motorola Bionic - input type textPersonName and textCapWords not working

Tags: android, input, android-softkeyboard

I can't get an EditText field in my app to actually work with inputType="textCapWords" or "textPersonName" on a Droid Bionic. Other phones I've tested seem to be fine. None of the capitalization inputTypes seem to work. I've also tried the deprecated capitalization attribute. And setting things programmatically.

Has anyone else run into this problem? Any suggestions aside from implementing custom functionality using TextWatcher?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/last_name_editor"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/last_name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either this is a problem specific to me, or nobody seems to have a solution. Went with a TextWatcher solution. Will change this if anybody else comes up with a solution.

Comment: I have posted the TextWatcther Way, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Can you check your Device keyboard setting .In some device(Samsung Note 2) they give auto Capitalization check /UN-check option.

Comment: In Marshmallow, it can be caused Google keyboard setting "Capitalize first word of every sentence" OFF which I prefer to turn off (because it doesn't know a simple abbreviation or decimal point from a sentence), but doing so prevents textCapWords from working properly.  So again, too many autocorrect type features get in the way more than help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the TextWatcher way, for anyone who is still facing this problem:

```
TextWatcher capitalizeTW = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        try{
            String inputString = ""+YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.getText().toString();
            String firstLetterCapString = WordUtils.capitalize(inputString);
            if(!firstLetterCapString.equals(""+YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.getText().toString())){
                YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.setText(""+firstLetterCapString);
                YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.setSelection(YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.getText().length());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
};
```

//Adding TextWatcher to Your TextView

```
YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.addTextChangedListener(capitalizeTW);
```

//WordUtils

```
public final class WordUtils {

private WordUtils(){

}

public static String capitalize(String str) {
    return capitalize(str, (char[]) null);
}

public static String capitalize(String str, char... delimiters) {
    int delimLen = delimiters == null ? -1 : delimiters.length;
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str) && delimLen != 0) {
        char[] buffer = str.toCharArray();
        boolean capitalizeNext = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
            char ch = buffer[i];
            if (isDelimiter(ch, delimiters)) {
                capitalizeNext = true;
            } else if (capitalizeNext) {
                buffer[i] = Character.toTitleCase(ch);
                capitalizeNext = false;
            }
        }

        return new String(buffer);
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}

private static boolean isDelimiter(char ch, char[] delimiters) {
    if (delimiters == null) {
        return Character.isWhitespace(ch);
    } else {
        char[] arr$ = delimiters;
        int len$ = delimiters.length;

        for (int i$ = 0; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
            char delimiter = arr$[i$];
            if (ch == delimiter) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this ... worked for me ...

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

Or

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

Or

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

For **Samsung S5/S7** there is additional settings in settings named **"Auto Capitalize"** for making first charterer in Caps.

If the settings is off it need to selected to type first character in Caps